# Rails 4 Devise custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using 'devise', '~> 3.4.1' and rails 4 in my app.  When I try to create custom routes am getting wiered error. What else I need to add in my route.rb

Error:
      ArgumentError: ' devise/sessions' is not a supported controller name. 
      This can lead to    potential routing problems.
       [See](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)

routes.rb

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

   devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get 'login', to: ' devise/sessions#new', as: :login
 end
```

The problem occured  at login route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, a space before 'devise/sessions#new'.

This,

```
get 'login', to: ' devise/sessions#new', as: :login
```

should be

```
get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code:

```
devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/register' => 'devise/registrations#new'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it this

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {
  sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout',
  password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification',
  registration: 'register', edit: 'edit/profile'
}
```

Source:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for

Comment: I changed my code as you said nothing changed. Btw as is alias for device_scope. It won't make anything difference. Thanks

Comment: @Prabhakar yes. I got it. Are you using custom controller or making use of devise's own controller?

Comment: I am not using any custom controller.

Comment: Can you check whether this path exists in your project app/views/devise/sessions ?

Comment: I'm creating custom routes that path does not exist in devise/sessions.

It works well on Rails 3 but not in Rails 4

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Does devise folder exists in app/view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67612/discussion-between-ajinkya-pisal-and-prabhakar).

Answer (score 0):

```
 devise_for  :user, :path => ' ', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login" :sign_up => "register" }
```